# Linux cannot type Alt-{ but can type Alt-}

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

## Background

Well this is weird... a bit of information about the background:

- I'm using Debian 9;
- I'm using an Italian keyboard so the keys actually typed are <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>è</kbd> (while <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for `}`);
- my keyboard is: Logitech Y-SG13 Corded Deluxe Access Keyboard.

[image: Italian QWERTY]

## Issue

Well as the title says <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>è</kbd> is not processed. I initially noticed this using Emacs, but after some testing I realized that the problem is more low-level. Here is how I figure it out.

Assuming `/dev/input/event0` is the device file associated to the keyboard I tried:

```
$ sudo hd /dev/input/event0
```

While I see raw event data for `Alt-}` nothing is generated for `Alt-{`.

This happens in both X and virtual consoles.

## Note

Apparently, with this layout, `{` and `}` can be also typed with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> respectively. Using the above everything works fine.

I tried another keyboard in the same conditions and it was able to properly interpret that sequence.

## Question

I'm not looking for a workaround, I know how to remap keys and circumvent this problem, rather I'm interested in understanding why does this happen and how to debug it.

Comment: Sounds like a ghosting issue to me.

Comment: Edit: added the keyboard model.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams well, yeah you may be right! Unfortunately I think it's very hard/not worth it to prove it. If that's the case, I think you might just convert this comment into an answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OK I tried another keyboard and worked just fine; while yet another on a different machine (same OS) wasn't able to interpret neither. So I guess this is really a ghosting issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://superuser.com/users/26316/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) [pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/1267653/linux-cannot-type-alt-but-can-type-alt/1271872#comment1867448_1267653), this is probably a *ghosting* issue since it does not happen with another keyboard.

Find more info [here](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx):

> "Ghosting" is the problem that some keyboard keys don't work when multiple keys are pressed simultaneously. The key presses that don't show up on the computer or seem to have disappeared are said to have been "ghosted".